# Discord channel.edit(position=2) still goes to the top

Tags: python, position, discord, channel

I am using await channel.edit(position=2) to change the position of a newly created channel to the 3rd spot from the top. However, it keeps jumping to the top of the category. What am i doing wrong?

When I add print(text_channel.position), it gives me 2 but it still jumps to the top of the category. Any idea? I've tried playing around with setting the position to 3 but it still jumps to the top.

```
text_channel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(channel_name, category=category)
await text_channel.edit(position=2)
```

Comment: Can you show the code of that process to see the wrong?

Comment: @Mr.Wrecker added the code i'm using to my question. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Apparently discord does not sort it as expected. I had to check the channel position of where i wanted it to be (in my case, 2nd spot from the top of the category needed a position = 4) and then use that position to specify where i wanted my new channel created.

For anyone who needs the code:

```
@bot.command(name='check')
async def check_pos(ctx):
    channel = ctx.channel
    channel_position = channel.position
    print(channel_position)
```